# R API to be accessible over the web

Tags: r, api, plumber

Hi I have R code which I have converted into an API using the **plumber** package.

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("code.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

The code sits in the file `code.R` and using the above lines I am able to access the API from my local machine from the URL http://localhost:8000/functionname

However when I replace the local host with my IP address and access the same from other machines in the network, I am unable to access the API. Why is that?

Comment: are you inputting the port number number too?

Comment: ya port number is 8000

Comment: what is the error

Answer (score 6):

making the host explicit works on my machine.

```
r$run(host = "0.0.0.0",port=8000)
```

and then to access it it is just

```
your_ip:8000/functionname
```

Answer (score 2):

By default plumber listens on the host 0.0.0.0 which means it should be listening on all devices, whether your IP or localhost. It sounds like either your machine has a firewall or your organization might have a firewall in front of the machine you're using. You'd also need to confirm that the IP address is routable (e.g. you're not trying to access a 192.168.*.* address from another LAN).

I'd discourage you from actually trying to host an API on your personal machine or a server where you're doing iterative development, as it requires opening up your firewall and accepting traffic on a more sensitive server. The best practice here would be to deploy your API to a server that's intended to receive public traffic. Here's one easy way to get that setup that's now built in to the development version of plumber: 
https://plumber.trestletech.com/docs/digitalocean/